# Nokogiri 1.6.0 still pulls in wrong version of libxml on OS X

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, nokogiri

There are questions (and answers) all over the net (including Stack Overflow) about warnings like this one:

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, 
but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
```

**This was [supposed to be fixed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nokogiri-talk/dt6baTiT4Zw/FiWr9B0Pb9kJ) by Nokogiri 1.6.0:**

> This version of Nokogiri ships and compiles libxml2 and libxslt with
>       the gem. This should fix most installation issues.

So I uninstalled the brew versions of the libraries and installed the new Nokogiri 1.6.0 gem (on Mac OS 10.8.4 using `rvm 1.18.14`.  `nokogiri -v` outputs

```
# Nokogiri (1.6.0)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.6.0
    ruby:
      version: 1.9.3
      platform: x86_64-darwin12.4.0
      description: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: packaged
      libxml2_path: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0
      libxslt_path: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26
      compiled: 2.8.0
      loaded: 2.8.0
```

So I thought my problems were solved.  But no.   My Rails 3.2.14 app still gives me that same warning:

```
user$ rails c
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
```

WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the good news is that Nokogiri 1.6.0 really does solve the mismatched LibXML problem! All the other tricks on the web about getting older versions of Nokogiri to build and load correctly are no longer needed.  ***If you are getting this warning, first thing to do is upgrade your Nokogiri to at least 1.6.0***

The new caveat is that you have to have Nokogiri load ***before any other library that needs LibXML***.  In my case, RMagick indirectly loaded the system LibXML library (2.7.8) before Nokogiri loaded.

The solution is to move `gem 'nokogiri'` to the top of your `Gemfile` so that it loads first and thus loads its packaged LibXML library (the one it was compiled against).  If it's not in your Gemfile at all, then it is being pulled in by something that depends on it and you can just add `gem 'nokogiri'` as the first gem anyway.

FYI, you can determine the order in which libraries are loading (and thus infer what gem is causing what libraries to load) by setting the environment variable `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES`, as in

```
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 rails c
```